# A question regarding the tower of hanoi recursive algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

I am doing a coding exercise today. After finishing the examination, I checked the results and I faced a problem whose problem statement is shown as follows:

*Given 4 disks in the tower of Hanoi problem, the recursive algorithm calls the same function at most ___ times.*
A. 10
B. 16
C. 22
D. 31
The only thing I knew is that I selected B. 16 and I was wrong.
I searched on the internet upon discovering that it should be 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 times, or 15 times.
However, it was not in the options.
Which option is correct?
Any advice will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe they mean something my saying "at most". 2^n -1 which is 15 for 4 disks is "the minimum" required moves to solve the puzzle but you can add unnecessary steps in the sequence. Not sure about the correct answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4-disk puzzle takes 15 moves.  The number of recursive calls, though, depends on how it's implemented.

If your recursive base case is 1 disk => 1 move, then it's 15.  If your recursive base case is 0 disks => 0 moves, then it's 31.